# Dialog full screen layout issue

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, dialog, android-constraintlayout

The layout in a full screen dialog is not rendered properly.

This is my dialog code:

val mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_info, null)

```
    val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.FullScreenDialog)
            .setView(mDialogView)

    val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()

    mDialogView.titleTv.text = getString(R.string.title)
    mDialogView.descriptionTv.text = getString(R.string.description)

    mAlertDialog.show()
```

in style.xml this is my FullScreenDialog:

```
<style name="FullScreenDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/md_white_1000</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

And this is my layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="@color/md_white_1000">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iconIv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_success"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/titleTv" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleTv"
                    style="@style/FontLocalizedBold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="@string/payment_success"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/descriptionTv"
                    style="@style/FontLocalizedMedium"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    tools:text="@string/payment_success_description"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleTv" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/okTv"
                    style="@style/ButtonTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/save_button_active"
                    android:text="@string/done"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried with LinearLayout instead of ConstraintLayout, but same result.

I have attached pictures with how my xml file look, and how it looks rendered on emulator, ignore please different string values.

emulator:
[image: emulator]

xml:
[image: xml]

Any idea what can cause the difference in rendering?

Comment: Did you select the style you are using in the XML editor to FullScreenDialog? If not it'll be set to the default AppTheme

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Comment: I added an answer with a pic for you. Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to update the preview style in the xml viewer. I highlighted the drop down box to use in the current release of AndroidStudio.

[image: Click dropdown box to change preview style]